# How to iterate properly over cursor in teradata sql?

Tags: sql, teradata

How to iterate  correctly over cursor in Teradata SQL?

```
while sql code = 0 
fetch cursor_name into (...)
do something...
end while;
```

This doesn't work properly. I had heard about something like 
for loop cursor, but I found only comparison to casual cursor in documentation, there is no declaration example NOWHERE.

Comment: I don't know where you looked, but there're lots of examples in the manuals:  http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_015K/ch03.138.133.html#ww11237872 Just be careful, this manual mixes Embedded SQL & Stored Procedures syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example:

```
    FOR fReq AS cReq CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Col1
        FROM Some_Table
    DO
        SET MyVariable = fReq.Col1
        ...
    END FOR;
```

From what I remember, you never refer to the cursor name (cReq), but you use the FOR alias (fReq) to reference the source query columns.